# How to unlink Object Texture (material) in blender

Tags: materials, modifiers, texture-painting

[image][![Hello.
I'm trying to create a wood texture on fence plank in Blender(3.1.2).
I'd put the texture on one plank, and then linked the rest of the plant to the one with the texture to copy it's materials. But the catch here is that, what ever changes I made on one plank, it reflects on the other making all planks look similar. I know this is because I had linked all planks to the same texture, but is there a way I can:

- Unlink the planks texture from the others but still retain the texture so I can make changes on one without it affecting the other?
- I do not want to start a new texture afresh on each plank.][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGZE7.jpg)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGZE7.jpg)

Thank you.

(If anyone can help rephrase the Title, I'd be grateful)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the fence using Array modifier **first** and texture the whole fence **next**. Blender treats the arrayed fence as **one** object and applies the texture the way each plank looks different. In fact it's one texture but with different parts visible.

Answer (score 0):

yes. You should be able to have the look you looking for by using a Node Group. by doing so you will retain the look of your "parent" plank as the default setting then a little tinkering with your randomization (I'm assuming your using a noise node to get the wood look). and you should have a different pattern with the least amount of effort.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to link-duplicate the same plank and the same material, and make each plank look different, it means that the UV location of each plank is randomized, I don't know if it's possible, maybe someone will tell.

Another way would be to use an empty as reference to project the image texture on the plank:

[image]

To do so you need to use the *Object* output of the *Texture Coordinate* and select an empty as object. Also select *Box* instead of *Flat* in the *Image Texture*:

[image]

Another solution would be to link-duplicate the plank but unlink the material (to unlik the material, click on the *Link Material* button and select *Object*, see below), then move the UV a bit in the *UV Editor*:

[image]

But it looks like you want to keep only one material...

In my opinion the simplest way to create a bit of variety would be to join several planks (like for example 3), unwrap and give them the wood material:

[image]

Then link-duplicate and rotate on Z to show the other side, now you have 6 planks that don't look the same. If you link-duplicate these 6 planks the repetition won't be noticeable imho:

[image]